# CSS keyframes and animation: pulse don't work on Safari and border-radius won't apply to the pulse effect

Tags: safari, bootstrap-4, css-animations, pulse

**Problem 1**: I can't get the animation to pulse in Safari browser (11.1 and 12.0 on Mac).
Specificly the `.pulse-btn .btn2`.

The `.pulse-btn .btn1`, with the `shadow-pulse` and `box-shadow`, work as intended.

**Problem 2**: I can't get `border-radius` effect to apply to the pulsing animation in any browser I try, `.pulse-btn .btn2`.

I'm using `bootstrap 4.0` and I follow the structure and syntax from: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/#article-header-id-7 but can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class='pulse-btn'>

    <button class='btn btn-primary giftBtn pulse-border'>BUTTON</button>
    <br><br>
    <button class='btn btn1 btn-primary giftBtn'>BUTTON</button>
    <br><br>
    <button class='btn btn2 btn-primary giftBtn'>BUTTON</button>

</div>

.giftBtn {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #f7beca;
    color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
}

.pulse-btn {
    text-align: center;
}

.pulse-btn .btn1 {
    animation: shadow-pulse 1s infinite;
}

.pulse-btn .btn2 {
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
       -moz-animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
         -o-animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
            animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        outline: 1px solid #C56378;
        outline-offset: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    30% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0.7);
        outline-offset: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    60% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    100% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 30px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        outline: 1px solid #C56378;
        outline-offset: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    30% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0.7);
        outline-offset: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    60% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    100% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 30px;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        outline: 1px solid #C56378;
        outline-offset: 0px;
        -o-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    30% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0.7);
        outline-offset: 5px;
        -o-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    60% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 10px;
        -o-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    100% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 30px;
        -o-border-radius: 7px;
    }
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        outline: 1px solid #C56378;
        outline-offset: 0px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
    30% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0.7);
        outline-offset: 5px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
    60% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 10px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
    100% {
        outline: 1px solid rgba(197, 99, 120, 0);
        outline-offset: 30px;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }
}

@keyframes shadow-pulse {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So.. There was a `-moz-outline-radius` I wasn't aware of and it only works with mozilla.

Worth noting is that the correct propery name of what I was asking is **`-moz-outline-radius`**, not `border-radius`.

[edit]: So that takes care of **Problem 2**. I still would like to find an answer to the Safari pulse animation problem.

```
.pulse-btn .btn2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;

    -moz-outline-radius: 7px; /* ONLY WORKS WITH MOZILLA */

    -webkit-animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
       -moz-animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
         -o-animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
            animation: pulse 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.66, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99) infinite;
}
```